# Reactive - Improve Mono syntax

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I have this block of code that works fine:

```
return isBlacklistedToken(refreshToken, Boolean.TRUE).flatMap(isBlacklisted -> {
    if (isBlacklisted)
        return Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException(format("The user %s has already logged out.", username)));
    else
        return isBlacklistedToken(accessToken, Boolean.FALSE).flatMap(isABlacklisted -> {
            if (isABlacklisted)
                return Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException(format("The user %s has already logged out.", username)));
            else
                return blacklistTokens(username, refreshToken, accessToken);
        });
});
```

To summarize it:

- calls the `isBlacklistedToken` function (returns a `Mono<Boolean>` with the result of the refresh token)
- If the `refresh` token is blacklisted, throws an `UnauthorizedException`
- If the `refresh` token is not blacklisted, does the same process for the `access` token
- If both tokens are not blacklisted, finally blacklists them.

This syntax, while it works, seems a bit sloppy. Is there a way to improve that? I wrote this piece of code, and while it throws an exception, the last part (blacklisting the tokens) always executes - peraphs my knowledge of reactive programming is a bit off.

```
return isBlacklistedToken(refreshToken, Boolean.TRUE)
                .flatMap(isBlacklisted -> isBlacklisted ? Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException(format("The user %s has already logged out.", username))) : Mono.empty())
                .then(isBlacklistedToken(accessToken, Boolean.FALSE))
                .flatMap(isBlacklisted -> isBlacklisted ? Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException(format("The user %s has already logged out.", username))) : Mono.empty())
                .then(blacklistTokens(username, refreshToken, accessToken));
```

Edit: adding the `isBlacklistedToken` method

```
private Mono<Boolean> isBlacklistedToken(final String token, final Boolean type) {

        return blacklistService.isBlacklisted(token, type);
    }
```

and the respective `blacklistService` call (just a repository call, really simple)

```
public Mono<Boolean> isBlacklisted(final String token, final Boolean isRefresh) {
        return Mono.just(this.blacklistRepository.existsBlacklistByTokenAndIsRefresh(token, isRefresh));
    }
```

Comment: Can you share  `isBlacklistedToken()`?  Maybe, retrying inside `isBlacklistedToken()` using `RetrySpec` is better option.

Comment: Added the method you asked. Also, gonna learn about that RetrySpec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```java
return isBlacklistedToken(refreshToken, Boolean.TRUE)                 
    .filter(isBlacklisted -> !isBlacklisted)                 
    .flatMap(isBlacklisted -> isBlacklistedToken(accessToken, Boolean.FALSE))                 
    .filter(isBlacklisted -> !isBlacklisted)                 
    .flatMap(isBlacklisted -> blacklistTokens(username, refreshToken, accessToken))                 
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException(format("The user %s has already logged out.", username))));
```

Sorry if there is some compile error but I tried this in Kotlin and needed to translate it to Java, which is become less and less easy.

Comment: I fixed the syntax into this:

`return isBlacklistedToken(refreshToken, Boolean.TRUE)
                .filter(isBlacklisted -> !isBlacklisted)
                .flatMap(isBlacklisted -> isBlacklistedToken(accessToken, Boolean.FALSE))
                .filter(isBlacklisted -> !isBlacklisted)
                .flatMap(isBlacklisted -> blacklistTokens(username, refreshToken, accessToken))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException(format("The user %s has already logged out.", username))));`

That works properly, and it's more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer so that it does not mislead other people looking for a similar solution.